# Is there a Solution for NGINX proxy for shadowsocks-client (socks5)

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to make NginX use proxies while connecting to shadowsocks-client, something like the following.

The setting of the proxy server is generally like this:

```
Browser[SwitchyOmega] -> shadowsocks-client --> shadowsocks-server[Self-built server or shared by others]  --> Remote
```

For redundancy and load balancing:

```
Browser[SwitchyOmega] -> nginx -- shadowsocks-client[all in one server with diffent port] --> shadowsocks-server[Self-built server or shared by others]  --> Remote
```

Comment: @double-beep ←_← thinks a lot

Comment: '''# get nginx
RUN git clone https://github.com/nginx/nginx.git \
 && git clone https://github.com/zhouchangxun/ngx_healthcheck_module.git \
 && cd nginx/ \
 && git checkout branches/stable-1.12 \
 && git apply ../ngx_healthcheck_module/nginx_healthcheck_for_nginx_1.12+.patch \
 && mkdir -p /opt/nginx \
 && ./auto/configure --prefix=/opt/nginx --with-pcre --with-stream --add-module=../ngx_healthcheck_module/ \
 && make && make install'''

Comment: use nginx-1.12 configure  --with-stream

Answer (score 0):

```
# get nginx
RUN git clone https://github.com/nginx/nginx.git \
    && git clone https://github.com/zhouchangxun/ngx_healthcheck_module.git \
    && cd nginx/    \
    && git checkout branches/stable-1.12    \
    && git apply ../ngx_healthcheck_module/nginx_healthcheck_for_nginx_1.12+.patch  \
    && mkdir -p /opt/nginx  \
    && ./auto/configure --prefix=/opt/nginx --with-pcre --with-stream --add-module=../ngx_healthcheck_module/   \
    && make && make install
```